# How can you type in Minecraft enchantment table font?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So me and my friend want to message each other in the Minecraft enchantment table lettering and it would be great if someone had an idea on how to do it.

Comment: That duplicate applies to using SGA for naming objects, though, not for using it in chat (not sure if that makes a lot of difference).

Answer (score 0):

The Minecraft enchantment table uses the Standard Galactic Alphabet, originally from Commander Keen. It's not particularly easy to type with it normally, however, you can find translators online [such as this one](https://lingojam.com/StandardGalacticAlphabet)

Comment: Since the SGA is basically just a substitution cipher, all you'd really need is a font that changes the letters to their SGA equivalent.

Comment: @MageXy it doesn't appear to be a font, they appear to be unicode characters (otherwise how are they rendering on my browser, and how can I copy ℸ ̣ ᒷᓭℸ to my clipboard)

Comment: My guess is that the author of that website is just using closest Unicode approximations. If you compare what you typed with the actual characters from the games, you'd see they are pretty different. https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/sga.htm